# How can I get CSS selector for text wrapped in a paragraph under<p> tag

Tags: css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to capture an URL in a mail paragraph using a Xpath selector (Xpath: html/body/p[2]/text()[3]). I could not get a proper css selector but with Xpath, I'm getting an error as given below when executing the Selenium webdriver test.

```
<body>
<p>Dear EmailTest user,</p>
<p>
Your profile on the Swwebsite has been successfully created.
<br/>
To begin, click on the link below. You will be prompted to create a password during the login process.
<br/>
https://test.website.com/one/portal/$swweb/?uri=emailuser-125633uu3d-452iekdkd
<br/>
After creating your password, you will be able to access your application with the below username:
<br/>
User Name emailuser_test
<br/>
</p>
```

Getting the below error:

> com.ibm.automation.wtf.driver.DriverException: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
>   Build info: version: '3.5.2', revision: '10229a9', time: '2017-08-21T17:29:55.15Z'

On some search over internet it seemed a Firefox issue with CSS. Can somebody help me here in fixing the issue or getting a proper CSS selector for capturing URL in the mail

> System info: host: 'IBM345-R902EWZ3', ip: '9.162.252.164', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Comment: Here is the Xpath the I've used which seems correct when I search in the webpage with mail: html/body/p[2]/text()[3]

Comment: Please show us your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get whole mail body under `<p>` tag using `getText()` method, then capturing the URL using Java String operation like split/substring/indexOf method.

Use cssSelector like below:

```
String mailBody = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > p:nth-child(2)")).getText();
```

Now parsing the string to capture the URL. 
For example:

```
String[] temp = mailBody.split("\n");
String url = temp[2];
System.out.println(url);
```

Or

```
int startIndex = mailBody.indexOf("https");
int endIndex = mailBody.indexOf("After creating your password");
String url = mailBody.substring(startIndex, endIndex - 1);
System.out.println(url);
```

Or you can use any string operation(or regex) to search for the URL from `mailBody` string

Another try:
You can also get the whole mail body using xpath `html/body/p[2]` and then parse the string.

Comment: Thank you Ali Azam and all , could capture the URL with the Split option given above.

Comment: @Vizag I would be more happy if you point a tick mark and accept the answer. Most appreciated.

Comment: @Vizag if you get really help from it you should vote up and tick mark on it. Thanks

Comment: Tried Voting up earlier, but I think my current privileges didn't allow that  but I ticked & did accepted the answer. Thanks again for the help :-)

Comment: @Vizag you need 15 reputation to do that I think. If I vote up the question you will get that. Then try to do that again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Java :

To capture the **`URL`** we will first capture the total text under the second **`<p>`** tag, then split it once with [positive lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to include **`https`** in the right hand side, then again split it again with [positive lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to include **`After`** in the right hand side and finally print the remaining left hand part. To achieve this you can use the following block of code :

```
String myText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body//following::p[2]")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
String[] textParts = myText.split("(?=https)");
String mySubtext = textParts[1];
String[] subparts = mySubtext.split("(?=After)");
String text = subparts[0];
System.out.println(text);
```

This prints the following on my console :

```
https://test.website.com/one/portal/$swweb/?uri=emailuser-125633uu3d-452iekdkd
```